# How to create a SQL Server Pivot query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

I want to create sql query result. I want to dynamically create because of inventory locations are one or more. (Example.. CTE)

```
Item_id     Location    Qty
 --------------------------
 1              a       1    
 2              b       2
 3              c       3
 3              a       1
 2              c       2
 1              b       3
```

Result is....

```
 Item_id    a_Location_Qty  b_Location_Qty  c_Location_Qty
 -------------------------------------------------------
 1          1               3               0
 2          0               2               2
 3          1               0               3
```

Comment: Provide your SQL query code, in order for us to analyze the problem and help you out. Thanks!

Comment: Google : Pivot in Sql Server

Comment: Anything more?  Message too short.

Comment: I want to create the total qty of location column by column. But my sql code is static. (nested select and inner join statement).

Comment: @MayHnin Using dynamic sql, If inventory location is three or more also it will works

Answer (score 0):

Please try below code

```
  Create Table #Stack10072017040904(Item_id varchar(100),Location varchar(100),Qty int)
 insert into #Stack10072017040904 select '1','a','1'
 insert into #Stack10072017040904 select '2','b','2'
 insert into #Stack10072017040904 select '3','c','3'
 insert into #Stack10072017040904 select '3','a','1'
 insert into #Stack10072017040904 select '2','c','2'
 insert into #Stack10072017040904 select '1','b','3'
select Item_id,Isnull(a,0) a_Location_Qty
,isnull(b,0)b_Location_Qty  
,isnull(c,0)c_Location_Qty  
from #Stack10072017040904
pivot
(Sum(Qty) for Location in ([a],[b],c) )pvt
drop table #Stack10072017040904
```

Comment: If inventory location is three or more, I will edit or add my sql statement??

Answer (score 0):

Try this Dynamic Sql

```
Declare 
         @Sql nvarchar(max),
         @dynamicCol nvarchar(max),
         @dynamicCol2 nvarchar(max)
--Create columns Dynamically
SELECT @dynamicCol=STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT ', '+ QUOTENAME(Location )
From  #Stack10072017040904 For XML PATH ('')),1,1,'')

SELECT @dynamicCol2=STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT ', '+ 'ISNULL ('+ QUOTENAME(Location )+ ','+'''0'''+')' +' AS '+Location+'_Location_Qty'
From  #Stack10072017040904 For XML PATH ('')),1,1,'')

SET @Sql='
SELECT [Item_id] ,'+ @dynamicCol2 +' From
(
SELECT *  From
#Stack10072017040904
)AS Src
PIVOT 
(
MAX([Qty]) For [Location] IN ('+@dynamicCol+')
)
AS Pvt'

PRINT @Sql

EXEC(@Sql)
```

Result

```
Item_id    a_Location_Qty  b_Location_Qty  c_Location_Qty
 -------------------------------------------------------
 1          1               3               0
 2          0               2               2
 3          1               0               3
```

Answer (score 0):

Build columns dynamically and use a dynamic PIVOT:

```
Create Table #Test(Item_id varchar(100),Location varchar(100),Qty int)
insert into #Test values( '1','a','1')
insert into #Test values( '2','b','2')
insert into #Test values( '3','c','3')
insert into #Test values( '3','a','1')
insert into #Test values( '2','c','2')
insert into #Test values( '1','b','3')

DECLARE @cols1 AS NVARCHAR(MAX), @cols2 AS NVARCHAR(MAX), @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @cols1 = STUFF((SELECT distinct ', isnull(' + quotename(s.Location) + ', 0) as ' + quotename(s.Location)
            FROM #Test s
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

SET @cols2 = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + quotename(s.Location) 
            FROM #Test s
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query = 'SELECT Item_id, ' + @cols1 + ' from 
            (
                select Item_id
                    , Location
                    , Qty
                from #Test
           ) x
            pivot 
            (
                 max(qty)
                for Location in (' + @cols2 + ')
            ) p '

execute(@query)

drop table #Test
```